# Do I charge vat on work i did before being VAT registered that has only just been invoiced?

Tags: united-kingdom, vat

Before my VAT registration date I submitted various quotes, won the jobs and almost completed all of the work. (They are non VAT registered people that I have done the work for.) Now I have my vat number and am VAT registered it's time to invoice those clients. They will be very annoyed if I now add VAT to their bill because it was never mentioned at the time. (Some of these jobs were started weeks & months before my VAT registration date and I'm based in the UK).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration :

> While you wait
>
> You cannot charge or show VAT on your invoices until
> you get your VAT number. However, you’ll still have to pay the VAT to
> HMRC for this period.
>
> You should increase your prices to allow for this and tell your
> customers why. Once you’ve got your VAT number you can then reissue
> the invoices showing the VAT.

Of course, it's too late to follow that advice.  I imagine that if you add VAT to your invoices now, this would constitute a breach of contract (i.e., you told your customers one price but are now invoicing them for a higher price).

Comment: Thanks, I read that and understand that contracts made following my vat reg. date will be liable whether I have a vat number or not. My issue is with work I quoted for and actually carried out before my registration date. The only thing that has occurred since my voluntary registration date is I am submitting my invoice. (Background.. we do design work and customers can go silent for weeks and then out the blue they approve our artwork/designs)